optimizing pull and push to db with python csv and psycopg using airflow
I have a task in airflow that invokes a helper function, the helper function reads data from oracle db and writes that data into an io buffer in batches. Then once the buffer is ready I read from that buffer and write the data. I think the reading step should be fine in terms of memory footprint if i reduce the the amount of lines in read(INT) . But the writing step I am not sure if is very memory intensive since io buffers are stored in memory correct ? Perhaps I should write to disk and then read from disk instead of keeping in the buffer ? What is the best approach in term of having a low memory profile in this scenario ?
from airflow.decorators import task
def create_query_buffer(con: str, sql: str):
    import csv
    import io
    import time

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.prefetchrows = 17000
    cur.arraysize = 20000
    cur.execute(sql)
    start_time = time.time()
    # the buffer
    output = io.StringIO()
    # write into buffer csv style format
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator="\n")
    col_names = [row[0] for row in cur.description]
    writer.writerow(col_names)
    while True:
        rows = cur.fetchmany()
        if not rows:
            break
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row)
    print(
        f"Time to write the oracle query into buffer is {round(time.time() - start_time,2)} seconds"
    )
    output.seek(0)
    return output


@task
def stage_ods(
    queries: list[str], table_names: list[str], postgres_con: str, oracle_con: str
) -> None:
    import oracledb
    import psycopg
    from psycopg import sql

    oracle_con_ods = oracledb.connect(oracle_con)

    with psycopg.connect(postgres_con, autocommit=True) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()

        for query, table in zip(queries, table_names):
            stream = create_query_buffer(oracle_con_ods, query)
            columns = list(next(stream).rstrip().lower().split(","))

            with conn.transaction():
                cur.execute(
                    sql.SQL("TRUNCATE TABLE {} RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE").format(
                        sql.Identifier(table)
                    )
                )

                with cur.copy(
                    sql.SQL("COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV").format(
                        sql.Identifier(table),
                        sql.SQL(", ").join(map(sql.Identifier, columns)),
                    )
                ) as copy:
                    while data := stream.read():
                        copy.write(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stage_ods()


The mismatch between prefetchrows and arraysize is odd.  But regardless, since you are fetching a large number of rows you should almost certainly leave prefetchrows at its default. See the doc on Tuning Fetch Performance.

you are right, thanks. I just had a look at it .

Since both DB's drivers support the Python DB API standard, why not make use of executemany() for the insert step? See Copying Data between Databases.
